# Filter model by datetime in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need to filter model with (datetime.now() < end)
My model

```
class Quiz(models.Model) :
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    start = models.DateTimeFieldField(default="2021-10-10")
    end = models.DateTimeFieldField(default="2021-10-11")
```

My view

```
class GetQuizView(generics.ListAPIView) :
    def get_queryset(self):
        now = datetime.now()
        return Quiz.objects.filter(start = now)

    serializer_class = QuizListSerializer
```

But I can only filter with equal time, I can't use > or <

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your queryset to look like this

```py
class GetQuizView(generics.ListAPIView) :
    def get_queryset(self):
        now = datetime.now()
        end = "2021-10-11"
        return Quiz.objects.filter(start__range=[end, now])
     serializer_class = QuizListSerializer
```

Note that i hardcoded the value off end date which is not a good practice, you can easily specify the range (days) of your filter using the datetime library

Here is another code snippet

```py
import pytz
from datetime import date, timedelta
from django.conf import settings
#timezone aware object
today = datetime.today().astimezone(pytz.timezone(settings.TIME_ZONE))
one_week = timedelta(days=7)
end_date = today-one_week
class GetQuizView(generics.ListAPIView) :
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Quiz.objects.filter(start__range=[end_date, today])
     serializer_class = QuizListSerializer
```

You can also use the django `__lt`, and `__gt` filter as per [doc](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#gt)

**Note:** This essence of `astimezone()` is to make the query timezone aware, and then make the timezone inherit from your project timezone configuration as defined in your project `settings.py`

Comment: Thank you ! Sorry, I can't upvote because of my rating

Comment: You can mark it as Accepted answer if it answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

You would use `__gt`, `__lt`, `__gte` and `__lte`

See the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/

Comment: Thank you ! Sorry, I can't upvote because of my rating